# How to navigate in Xcode with mouse buttons

Tags: xcode, logitech-gaming-software

I would like to know if there is a way to bind a mouse button to a specific keyboard shortcut in Xcode. My specific use case here is to be able to navigate by using the mouse side buttons. It is possible in vscode to `Go Back` with <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> and `Go Forward` with <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> but my side mouse button (Logitech G402) also get mapped to this action.

In Xcode, I tried setting <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to `Go Back` and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to `Go Back in Next Editor` but the mouse button doesn't trigger the shortcut of the navigation action.

I know a workaround would be to create a profile in ghub only for Xcode, to bind the side button to a specific key binding and use this key binding in Xcode, but I was curious if there was another way to navigate with the mouse in Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of a workaround, but I've managed to make this work by running the [Sensible Side Buttons](https://sensible-side-buttons.archagon.net/) and GHub app side by side. Sensible Side Buttons dont have any impact on the macros I've created with GHub and XCode seems to recognize the navigation command when this app is running.

It can be downloaded with :

```bash
brew install --cask sensiblesidebuttons
```

Comment: There is a newer fork of that here: https://github.com/thealpa/SaneSideButtons that works better for me. No need for GHub as well.